# Sentence into word c++ string

Tags: c++, string

How to break down a sentence of string  type into words and store it in a vector of string type in c++?
Example

```
String str="my name";
```

Into

```
Vector word={" my","name"}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple loop:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;

std::istringstream is("my name");
std::string word;
while (is >> word) {
    // ...
    words.push_back(word);
    // ...
}
```

which in my opinion is good idea because you'll most likely need to do other things with those words apart the simple extraction of them. The body of the loop can be easily extended.